# Pulling recipient email address from a link within an email?

Tags: c#, .net, email, exchange-server, mailkit

I have a C# Mailkit program that automatically sends emails to an email list. I have a web server with a database filled with email addresses and I want to incorporate an unsubscribe link within my emails. Is there any way of tracking the email address of the person who clicked the link? I essentially just want to remove the email from the database of the person who unsubscribed.

Are there any kind of special links/anything I can do to pull the user's email address after they click the link?

thank you.

Comment: You can do something like https://my-awesome-mailer.com/unsubscribe?email=user@somemail.com But this way user can change mail to someone else's mail and unsubscribe them. What you can do is to encrypt email parameter when sending link and decrypt it when unsubscribe request gets on server.

Comment: you need it in the hyperlink when you create the message

Comment: Can you elaborate? What would be the implementation of this? When creating the email inside the code I would pass in the email address string into the link?

Comment: When creating email message with mailkit inside the body create unsubscribe link which contains email in query parameter.Like in my example above. That link needs to point to your web server on specific endpoint which can read email address from that query string and remove it from datsbase.

Comment: Don't use encryption for this. Don't pass user information like emails in links. When you send a user an email, store a GUID for that user or email and include it in the unsubscribe link; something like `http://example.com/unsubscribe/GUID HERE`. Your unsubscribe page looks up the email or user and unsubscribes them.

Comment: @DourHighArch What made you think he has user guid? :)

Comment: Thank you both for these great ideas. I will implement this.

Answer (score 0):

*"When creating email message with mailkit inside the body create unsubscribe link which contains email in query parameter.Like in my example above. That link needs to point to your web server on specific endpoint which can read email address from that query string and remove it from datsbase. – SlobodanT"*

*"Don't use encryption for this. Don't pass user information like emails in links. When you send a user an email, store a GUID for that user or email and include it in the unsubscribe link; something like http://example.com/unsubscribe/GUID HERE. Your unsubscribe page looks up the email or user and unsubscribes them. – Dour High Arch "*